# How can i create a subclass such that it does not use all attributes of super class?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I was practicing low level design of stack overflow and I came across a class structure

```
public class Post {
    public int postId;
    public PostBody postbody;
    public Date createdAt;
    public User user;
    public int upvotes;
    public int downvotes;
    public List<Comment> comments;
}

public class Question extends Post {
    public List<Answer> answer;
    public Topic topic;
    public List<Tag> tags;
}

public class Answer extends Post {
    public Bool isAcceptedAnswer;
}

public class PostBody {
    public String header;
    public String body;
    public String code;
}

public class Comment extends Post {
     public String comment;
}
```

Here, the Comment class is extending Post class. Either, I can consider the already defined PostBody class from the Post class or I can create a simple String inside the Comment class.

1. Can we implement an empty class? If no, then how should I implement the Comment class?
2. If I will add a comment attribute which is a string, the how to deal with the PostBody attribute that I am inheriting from the Post class?

Overall, How can I implement Comment class?

Comment: Why have you made Comment extend Post to start with? A comment isn't a post - it's *part* of a post, which you've already achieved via composition. (I'm not fully convinced about this question being on Stack Overflow, but it stands a better chance of staying open if you ask a single very concrete question. At the moment you appear to have lots of questions, but they're somewhat vague.)

Comment: To answer the question in your title, `How can i create a subclass such that it does not use all attributes of super class?`. You don't do that normally. Subclasses always inherit all non-private methods and attributes of the parent class.

Comment: When trying to create a sub class such that it is not supposed to use all attributes of parent, the whole concept of inheritance gets defeated.
For a quick workaround create a third class C that contains the common attributes and the other two classes can extend this class.